# Getting "501 Syntax error" when issuing RETR command to FTP server

Tags: java, ftp

I've made a FTP client that have `RETR` and `LIST` commands, but have got a problem. After I implemented the `RETR` command I keep getting this error:

```
1:220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.50 beta
1:220-written by Tim Kosse (tim.kosse@filezilla-project.org)
1:220 Please visit https://filezilla-project.org/
2331 Password required for geek
3230 Logged on
5227 Entering Passive Mode (127,0,0,1,217,137)
6200 Type set to A
7150 Opening data channel for directory listing of "/"
5227 Entering Passive Mode (127,0,0,1,217,139)
150 Opening data channel for directory listing of "/"
8501 Syntax error
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at ftp.ftp.connect(ftp.java:135)
at ftp.test.main(test.java:12)
```

Furthermore after I implemented the `RETR` command the client stopped giving the `LIST` command; it doesn't tell which files there are in the folder.

```
public class ftp{
public synchronized void connect(String host, int port, String user,
        String pass) throws IOException {
    Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));


    String response = reader.readLine();

    if (!response.startsWith("220-")) {
        throw new IOException(
                "FTP modtog et ukendt svar, da den blev forbundet til FTP server: "
                        + response);
    } else {System.out.println("1:"+response);
    response = reader.readLine();
    System.out.println("1:"+response);
    response = reader.readLine();
    System.out.println("1:"+response);


    }
    writer.write("user geek"+"\r\n");
    writer.flush();
    response= reader.readLine();
    System.out.println("2"+response);

    writer.write("PASS hello" +"\r\n");
    writer.flush();
    response= reader.readLine();
    System.out.println("3"+response);



    writer.write("pasv"+"\r\n");
    writer.flush();
    response= reader.readLine();
    System.out.println("5"+response );
    String [] r=response.trim().split(",");

    String reg=r[4];
    String add= r[5].replace(")", "");
    int m = Integer.parseInt(reg);
    int a = Integer.parseInt(add);

    int port1 = m*256+a;

    Socket datasocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", port1);
    writer.write("type A\r\n");
    writer.flush();
    response= reader.readLine();
    System.out.println("6"+response);
    BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(datasocket.getInputStream()));


    writer.write("LIST\r\n");
    writer.flush();
    response = reader.readLine();
    System.out.println("7" + response);

    List<String> files = new ArrayList<>();
    String text;
    while ((text = reader2.readLine()) != null) {
        String filename = parseFilename(text);
        files.add(filename);
    }
    reader2.close();
    datasocket.close();
    reader.readLine();

    for (String file : files) {
        int passivePort = getPort(reader, writer);
        writer.write("RETR\r\n");
        writer.flush();
        System.out.println(response);
        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[1024];

        try (Socket filesocket = new Socket("localhost", passivePort);
                InputStream is = filesocket.getInputStream();
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("c:/Users/Username/Desktop/FTP/" + file)) {
            int count;
            while ((count = is.read(mybytearray)) >= 0) {
                fos.write(mybytearray, 0, count);
            }
        }
    }

                writer.write("RETR\r\n");
            writer.flush();
            response= reader.readLine();
            System.out.println("8"+response);

                Socket filsocket = new Socket ("localhost", port1);
                InputStream is = null;
                FileOutputStream fos = null;

                byte[] mybytearray = new byte[1024];
            try {
                    is = filsocket.getInputStream();
                    fos = new FileOutputStream("myfile.txt");

                    int count;
                    while ((count = is.read(mybytearray)) >= 0) {
                        fos.write(mybytearray, 0, count);
                    }
                } finally {
                fos.close();
                    is.close();
                filsocket.close();
            }

}

private String parseFilename(String text) {

    return "abc.txt";
}

private int getPort(BufferedReader reader, BufferedWriter writer) throws IOException { //this is line 135
    String response;
    writer.write("PASV" + "\r\n");
    writer.flush();
    response = reader.readLine();
    System.out.println("5" + response);
    String[] r = response.trim().split(",");

    String reg = r[4];
    String add = r[5].replace(")", "");
    int m = Integer.parseInt(reg);
    int a = Integer.parseInt(add);

    return m * 256 + a;
}


}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Regarding the problem with `LIST`: server-side log would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RETR` command has a mandatory argument that specifies a name of the file to download. How would the server know, what file you want to download otherwise?

```
writer.write("RETR " + file + "\r\n");
```

See the [RFC 959](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc959#page-47):

```
RETR <SP> <pathname> <CRLF>
```

---

Anyway, why do you implement the FTP protocol on your own? Use some existing implementation, like the [`FTPClient` from Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html).